# How to make this postman request with laravel httpClient

Tags: laravel, httpclient, guzzle

I want to make a postman request with Laravel httpClient,the request in postman is like this:
[image]

The Content-Type in the header is: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
I tried many ways to make this request with Laravel httpClient, but it either return null or return all of the datas, not the data I am looking for.
I tried this:

```
 $res = Http::withHeaders([
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization' => 'Basic XXXXXXXXXX'
    ])->withBody(http_build_query(["uuid"=>$uuid]),"application/json")->post("https://xxx.com.cn/entity.find");
```

and also tried this:

```
    $res = Http::withHeaders([
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ZHh5LWVpbnRlbGxpZxxxxxxxx'
    ])->post("https://xxxx.com.cn/entity.find", [
        "form_params" => [
            "filter" => ['uuid'=>$uuid],
        ]
    
    ]);
```

All are not work. Could anyone give me some tips about this?

Comment: Try `Http::asForm()->withHeaders(...)->post([ 'uuid' => ... ])`

Comment: I had tried this,the request params is [ 'uuid' => "'a061aa4b-7289-4d7d-b1ae-f24f93149a28'"], but returns null, while in postman, it returns a value

Comment: Are you sure you're using the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http` facade?

Comment: I have resolved my problem by using Http::asForm() and removing the Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded  in header. Thank you a lot